# Наследование и DI

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

У меня есть простой класс Sender

```
public class Sender : ISender
    {
        private readonly FinMonitoringOptions options;
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public Sender(IOptionsSnapshot<FinMonitoringOptions> _options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            options = _options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("_options");
            logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Sender>() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("loggerFactory");
        }

        public async Task SendNotify(AlertCorp alert)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Sender.SendNotify IncidentId : {alert.IncidentId}");
            
        }
       

    }
```

теперь я хочу создать 2 класса-наследника EmailSender и ESBSender от этого же интерфейса ISender

```
public interface ISender
    {
        public Task SendNotify(AlertCorp alert);
    }
```

я использую DI от Microsoft и развязываю зависимости в Startup

```
.AddTransient<ISender, Sender>()
```

Вопрос: как мне получить в классе Sender потомков EmailSender и EsbSender через DI и вызвать их методы SendNotify ?

Answer (score 4):

Регистрируете оба типа как реализацию `ISender`:

```
services.AddTransient<ISender, EsbSender>();
services.AddTransient<ISender, EmailSender>();
```

В классе, который отправляет нотификации, добавляете зависимость от `IEnumerable<ISender> senders`.

```
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IEnumerable<ISender> senders)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _senders = senders;
}
```

В качестве значения senders от DI придет набор экземпляров всех зарегистрированных `ISender`.

Только не пытайтесь запихнуть управление отправкой через несколько `ISender` в базовый тип `Sender`. Это явно не его ответственность, заведите для этого отдельный класс, который знает про существование нескольких реализаций, и который будет выбирать, через какие именно отправлять.

Comment: очередность в IEnumerable соответствует порядку вызовов AddTransient? Или порядок не гарантируется?

Comment: @Grundy порядок гарантируется: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#service-registration-methods

Answer (score 0):

**Вопрос: как мне получить в классе Sender потомков EmailSender и EsbSender через DI и вызвать их методы SendNotify ?** - обычно это так не делается. Интерфейс вызывает свой метод. Который реализован в классе.

Согласно [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) - а конкретно **D - dependency inversion principle**

> Формулировка:
>
> - Модули верхних уровней не должны зависеть от модулей нижних уровней. Оба типа модулей должны зависеть от абстракций.
> - Абстракции не должны
>   зависеть от деталей. Детали должны зависеть от абстракций.

В вашем случае

```
public class EmailSender : ISender
    {
        private readonly FinMonitoringOptions options;
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public Sender(IOptionsSnapshot<FinMonitoringOptions> _options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            options = _options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("_options");
            logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Sender>() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("loggerFactory");
        }

        public async Task SendNotify(AlertCorp alert)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Sender.SendNotify IncidentId : {alert.IncidentId}");
            // send Email message
            
        }
    }
```

имея на руках только ISender. Вы должны вызвать метод sender.SendNotify(...) и не думать кто там на конце провода, который класс будет отсылать сообщение. В этом и есть основная идея интерфейсов.

А так можно в коде можно проверить что указатели совместимы и преобразовать

```
if (sender instanceof EmailSender)  {

 EmailSender emailSender  = (EmailSender)sender;
 ...
 // либо вариант. Кому как удобно
 // EmailSender emailSender  = sender AS EmailSender;
 ...
 emailSender."call EmailSender method"()

}
```

Comment: Не понятно, как получить в классе Sender объект EmailSender? Где прописать зависимости, что б Di создавал? Если создать отдельный интерфейс IEmailSender, то можно запросить через services.AddTransient, но поскольку в этом случае интерфейс IEmailSender идентичен ISender, как обойтись одним интерфейсрм?

Comment: Обновил ответ для ясности

Comment: "Как обойтись одним интерфейсом": это разные интерфейсы, одним не обойтись. И поэтому вопрос не имеет отношения к DI, он только из-за использования DI проявился явно - а до этого вы делали неправильно и не замечали проблемы.

Comment: Смысл в том, что сам Sender должен вызвать метод EmailSender.SendNotify и ESBSender.SendNotify. Но для этого класс Sender должен как то получить экземпляры этих объектов? Как? Можно, конечно, просто использовать шаблон цепочка обязанностей или еще что то, можно в самом классе Sender создать эти экземпляры, но это плохо, т.к. нужно использовать DI? А как указать одному интерфейсу несколько реализаций в Startup, если при множественном указании сопоставится последний?

Comment: @Hel, _как указать одному интерфейсу несколько реализаций в Startup_ - никак