# Как гарантированно выполнить код в 1 потоке после await c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность, async-await

Есть код:

```
public async void Method1()
{
    var t2 = Method2();       // thread 1
    var t3 = await Method3(); // async Thread 2
    var t3 = await Method4(); // async Thread 2 or 3 ???
}
```

Где будет выполнен `Method4` и как его заставить выполнятся в потоке 1 или потоке 2?

Comment: Ну гарантировано такое в однопоточном приложении, думаю.

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, не забудьте принять его, поставив галочку, расположенную слева от ответа. Так же будет неплохо, если вы примете наиболее полезный ответ в своем [прошлом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1230169/373567).

Comment: @aepot - Есть я. Я прихожу в вопрос, любуюсь Вашим ответом. я "плюсик" за ответ уже поставил. :-)

Comment: @S.H. автор заходил, но 0 эмоций. Что-то больше не хочется отвечать незарегистрированным участникам.

Comment: @aepot - вообще, я Вас понимаю, иногда столько сил тратишь, а в ответ - тишина... Но это скорее от непонимания системы сайта и того, как устроен рейтинг. Мы то здесь сравнительно давно сидим, а новому человеку сразу въехать не получается

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 6):

Если вы используете WinForms или WPF, то там и так присутствует контекст синхронизации. Ничего дополнительно делать не нужно, просто запускайте, и все методы будут выполнены в одном потоке, асинхронно.

В консольных же приложениях контекста синхронизации по умолчанию нет, и код после `await` продолжается в том потоке, в котором вернулся колбэк из вызванного с ожиданием метода. Есть хорошая статья в девблоге [Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/), в которой рассказано как реализовать однопоточный контекст синхронизации. Я просто создал пример на основе кода из этой статьи.

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Результаты в формате: [номер потока, количество запусков]");
        Console.WriteLine("Запуск на текущем потоке");
        RunOnSingleThread(TestContextAsync);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => RunOnSingleThread(TestContextAsync));
        Console.WriteLine($"Запуск на потоке номер {thread.ManagedThreadId}");
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Обычный запуск");
        await TestContextAsync();
    }

    static void RunOnSingleThread(Func<Task> method)
    {
        var context = new SingleThreadSynchronizationContext();
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
        Task task = method();
        task.ContinueWith(_ => context.Complete());
        context.RunOnCurrentThread();
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
        task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // таск уже гарантированно завершен, этот вызов нужен чтобы выдернуть из него исключение, если возникло.
    }

    static async Task TestContextAsync()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            dict[id] = dict.TryGetValue(id, out int count) ? count + 1 : 1;
            await Task.Yield();
        }

        foreach (var pair in dict)
            Console.WriteLine(pair);
    }
}

public sealed class SingleThreadSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<(SendOrPostCallback, object)> _queue = new BlockingCollection<(SendOrPostCallback, object)>();

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, object state)
    {
        _queue.Add((callback, state));
    }

    public void RunOnCurrentThread()
    {
        foreach ((SendOrPostCallback callback, object state) in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            callback(state);
    }

    public void Complete() 
    { 
        _queue.CompleteAdding(); 
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Результаты в формате: [номер потока, количество запусков]
Запуск на текущем потоке
[1, 1000]
Запуск на потоке номер 6
[6, 1000]
Обычный запуск
[1, 1]
[4, 235]
[5, 10]
[8, 14]
[7, 4]
[10, 11]
[9, 173]
[12, 272]
[11, 280]
```

Чтобы воспользваться этим кодом, вам нужно только изменить сигнатуру своего метода

```cs
public async Task Method1()
```

В противном случае всё сломается, так как работа контекста синхронизации будет завершена раньше, чем работа метода. Избегайте `async void` в методах - это плохая практика.

Comment: Уважаемый Aepot, мои самые тёпленькие слова восхищения! Только я хотел на автора вопроса поругаться - а тут Ваш ответ, и такой шикарный!