# С# | Работа с Task

Tags: c#, консоль, асинхронность, task

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, как правильно обращаться с Task'ами. Имею консольный проект. В нем расположен класс Program с методом Main(). Так же имею два других класса с методами Start(). Отсюда вопрос, как правильно реализовать асинхронное выполнение каждого из них? Нужно ли методам задавать возвращаемый тип Task или можно внутри методов создать задачи var task = new Task(async() => {...}) и после просто запустить task.Start(). Как вообще это правильно делается? И можно ли создавать List где будет храниться список всех запущенных задач и как-то потом контролироваться их выполнение, к примеру ожидание, пока не выполнятся некоторые из них?
Пример моего скорее всего неграмотного кода:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Client.Main();
    }
}

internal static class Client
{
    internal static List<Task> tasks { get; set; }

    internal static async Task Main()
    {            
        Bot.Start();
        Html.Start();
    }        
}

internal static class Bot
{
    internal static async Task Start()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            ...
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
}

internal static class Html
{
    internal static List<string> list { get; set; }

    internal static async Task Start()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            ...
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Вкратце о задумке. Есть телеграмм бот и какой-то парсящийся сайт. Эти задачи должны параллельно друг другу работать. Парсер должен постоянно обновлять свои данные, а бот должен забирать от парсера данные Html.list и пересылать их в группу, а так же принимать команды от пользователя и реагировать на них, например чтоб остановить парсер или запустить сканирование по другим параметрам. Вот я и думаю, как это грамотно можно сделать, а то у меня как-то не так все радужно выходит.

Comment: Почитайте про `async`/`await`, лучше сразу к правильному подходу приучаться: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: можно делать разное. Зачем спрашивать - просто пишите код, запускайте код, будут непонятнки - показывайте код и спрашивайте.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за хорошую статью - буду изучать.

Comment: @tym32167 дело в том, что я замучился искать правильное решение. Сначала делал так:
class program{ void main(){cl1.start(); cl2.start()}}
static class cl1{static async Task start(){await...}}
static class cl2{static async Task start(){await...}}
но IDE настаивает, что main тоже должен возвращать Task и тоже ожидать. А если вплоть до него task возвращать, то программа завершается по основному потоку. После делал через Task.Run(()=>{...await Task.Delay(100)}). Вроде все получилось, то что я хотел, но мне подсказали, что так делать тоже нехорошо. А вот как хорошо - вот я этого и не знаю.

Comment: добавьте ващ код в вопрос. Оформите его так, чтобы его можно было читать. Упомяните меня в комментариях, я погляжу.

Comment: @tym32167 Вроде бы оформил и немного глубже описал задачу. Я только учусь с Task'ами работать и не до конца их понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тема не простая, в двух словах не объяснить. Есть документация, лучше начать с нее.

Вот маленький пример.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
    tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => Multiply(1, 500));
    tasks[1] = GetNumberAsync();
    int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine($"Результаты: {results[0]}, {results[1]}");

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static int Multiply(int number, int times)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2);
        result += number;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("CPU вычисления завершены");
    return result;
}

static async Task<int> GetNumberAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Асинхронная операция завершена");
    return 42;
}
```

Смысл примера не только в том, что можно делать 100 дел одновременно, а в том что дела бывают разные. Бывают операции, требующие большой работы процессора - `Task.Run` именно для них. Бывают операции, требующие ответа из сети, от базы данных и т.д. Для таких операций запуск отдельного потока с помощью `Task.Run` не требуется. Их следует обязательно различать, потому что подходы к асинхронной реализации таких операций разные.

Да, здесь асинхронный `Main`, потому что мне требуется неблокирующее ожидание асинхронной операции `Task.WhenAll`, которая в свою очередь одновременно ожидает оба таска и завершается, когда оба завершены возвращая все результаты сразу.

Более подробно можно почитать здесь: [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Еще материалы

- [Thread'ы, Task'и, async'и, await'ы в C# под WPF на .NET Framework 4.8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567)

---

Не вникая в подробности, исправляю показанный код

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Client.Run();
    }
}

internal static class Client
{
    internal static List<Task> tasks { get; set; }

    internal static async Task Run()
    {            
        await Task.WhenAll(Bot.Start(), Html.Start());
    }        
}

internal static class Bot
{
    internal static async Task Start()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            ...
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
}

internal static class Html
{
    internal static List<string> list { get; set; }

    internal static async Task Start()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            ...
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот так будет работать, но я бы на вашем месте избавился бы от статиков.

Comment: Спасибо вам за хороший пример. Я немного развернул задачу выше. Вроде б мои задачи являются частично или даже полностью ответами сети. Но как понимаю такие операции нужно Runить? Так как они непрерывно должны обрабатываться и останавливаться только если придет в них команда остановить (как я понимаю токен на отмену). Но вот как это грамотно реализовать, и как их занести в List и при этом еще запустить правильно? При том, что не хочу привязываться к индексу (оттого и взял List). Подскажите, если несложно.

Comment: Вот так что ли?
    Client.tasks.Add(Task.Run(async() =>{...}));

Comment: Мне один тут уважаемый человечек еще говорил, что " async void плохо! Ведь его невозможно ожидать." Ибо Task.Delay() друг на друга будет накладываться в ожиданиях wait при последовательных вызовах, так же и ошибки будет сложно отловить. "если есть возможность, лучше делать отдельные Task, которые запускать как await SomeTask();". Но если честно, я пока не до конца понимаю, как без Run можно что-то еще сделать...

Comment: @eugenelly наду изучать, как это работает. `Task.Run` запускает поток явно. Но это в целом требуется только при выполнении синхронных операций. Асинхронные и так маршалируются правильно, а заботу о потоках берет на себя контекст синхронизации `SynchronizatiinContext` ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266905/373567)). То есть чтобы запустить асинхронный метод, его просто нужно вызвать и сразу `await` или не сразу потом подождать.

Comment: @eugenelly `async void` можно использовать тогда, и только тогда, когда вы на 100% уверены в том что вы делаете. В противном случае можете насобирать ненужных сюрпризов. Не спешите, осваивайте, тема действительно сложная.

Comment: @eugenelly для вызова `async` метода или делегата `Task.Run` может быть не только бесполезным, но и вредным. Старайтесь не делать так. Вызывайте асинхронные методы напрямую, как показано выше типа `tasks.Add(GetNumberAsync());`

Comment: Да тема действительно не из простых. Такая же как и делегаты. Только недавно начал их понимать и то не до конца. А так, я вот только начал практиковаться с тасками, чтоб, как раз, прочувствовать на практике данную тему, ибо я больше практик нежели теоретик.

Comment: Я попробовал так, как вы сказали, но видимо что-то еще требуется. Ибо я создал отдельный метод: internal static async Task<string> getResponceAsync(){string responce = await hc.GetStringAsync(url); await Task.Delay(500)} и в internal static void Start() добавил Client.tasks.Add(getResponceAsync()); и при этом он выдал "System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.""

Comment: @eugenelly дополнил ответ.

Comment: о, спасибо огромное. Вроде бы то, что нужно. Правда я так и не смог добавить задачу в List tasks. Так как при Client.tasks.Add(getResponceAsync()); мне нужно еще делать await getResponceAsync(), так как из этой функции я жду ответ с сервера по httpclient. Так что пока оставил эту затею со списком запущенных задач - думаю пока это излишне. А везде статики я делал из-за того, что у меня бот один и парсер один. Как бы в их экземлярах не нуждается проект. И я подумал, что статик как раз для этого и нужен.

Comment: @eugenelly список тасок лучше делать когда все таски однотипные. Чаще всего когда [запускается один и тот же метод несколько раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567). Но `await` можно применить ко всему списку `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`, а можно к отдельному элементу `await tasks[3];`. Ничего космически сложного. `await` съест любой таск, где бы он не лежал.