# Как выполнить асинхронный код в одном потоке

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-6

Ранее я уже писал ответ на подобный вопрос: [Как гарантированно выполнить код в 1 потоке после await c#.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1266820/373567)

Но возникла потребность многократно использовать прелести однопоточной синхронизации в приложении безо всяких блокировок используя асинхронный код. Известно же, что `lock` и прочие примитивы синхронизации в асинхронном коде использовать не получится. Ну разве что кроме семафора, но семафор - не совсем примитив.

Чтобы воспроизвести проблему, даже коллекция не нужна, можно запустить вот такой код:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await AddAsync(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(_counter);
}

static int _counter;

static async Task AddAsync(int count)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        tasks[i] = IncrementAsync();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

static async Task IncrementAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    _counter++;
}
```

И получить например вот такой вывод в консоль

```
969
```

А должно быть `1000`. Это значит, что код не является потокобезопасным. Если запустить этот код из UI потока в WPF или Winforms, он отработает корректно в 100% случаев и выдаст всегда `1000`. В предложенном решении по ссылке сам запуск контекста выглядит очень громоздским, и на каждый запуск нужно либо создавать новый поток, либо отдавать контексту текущий.

Хочется найти более простое решение, чтобы можно было в разных частях многопоточного кода перенаправлять вызовы в какой-то свой контекст, работающий в конкретном потоке.

Comment: Interlocked.Increment :)

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, но это всего-лишь абстрактный пример того что даже обычный асинхронный код иногда надо синхронизировать :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение очень похоже на прошлое, немного отличается. Но использовать гораздо проще, чем предыдущее. И можно иметь один контекст и переиспользовать его из разных углов приложения.

Суть решения в создании контекста, который берет себе 1 поток из пула и в нем работает до тех пор, пока его не задиспозить. При этом обращаясь в экземпляру контекста можно из любого места кода перенаправить вызов в тот самый поток.

Закидывать в контекст можно любой код, в том числе, синхронный, но назначение класса - именно дать возможнось запускать асинхронные методы так, чтобы `await`ы внутри метода не меняли поток после завершения асинхронного вызова, точно так же как это происходит в UI потоке десктопного приложения. За это отвечают 2 перегрузки метода `SendAsync`.

То есть появляется возможность использовать обычные коллекции и прочие прелести однопоточки без блокировок в коде. Это решение даже для UI приложений может оказаться полезным, когда хочется работать как в UI потоке с `async/await`, но при этом сам UI не нагружать.

```
public class SingleThreadedSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext, IDisposable
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<(SendOrPostCallback, object)> _queue = new();
    private readonly Task _task;

    public SingleThreadedSynchronizationContext()
    {
        _task = Task.Run(RunContext);
    }

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        _queue.Add((d, state));
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        if (Current == this)
            d(state);
        else
        {
            using ManualResetEventSlim mre = new();
            Post(s =>
            {
                try
                {
                    d(s);
                }
                finally
                {
                    mre.Set();
                }
            }, state);
            mre.Wait();
        }
    }

    public Task SendAsync(Func<Task> func)
    {
        if (Current == this)
            return func();
        Task task = null;
        Send(_ => task = func(), null);
        return task;
    }

    public Task<T> SendAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
    {
        if (Current == this)
            return func();
        Task<T> task = null;
        Send(_ => task = func(), null);
        return task;
    }

    private void RunContext()
    {
        SetSynchronizationContext(this);
        foreach ((SendOrPostCallback d, object state) in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            d(state);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
        _task.Wait();
    }
}
```

Проверяю.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using SingleThreadedSynchronizationContext context = new();
    await context.SendAsync(() => AddAsync(1000));
    Console.WriteLine(_counter);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
1000
```

Стоит только обратить внимание, что этот контекст не обрабатывает исключения. Вообще сам по себе контекст синхронизации не предназначен для обработчки исключений, их на самом деле обрабатывает сам `await`. Поэтому я не стал нагружать код обработками. Но стоит быть внимательным. Если в `Post` заслать вручную делегат, который сгенерит исключение, контекст упадет и не сможет больше обрабатывать вызовы. Если же вручную `Send` и `Post` не вызывать, то дорабатывать ничего не нужно.

---

Показываю, как обезопасить контекст от выброса исключений полностью. Для этого надо очень просто доработать пару методов.

```
public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
{
    if (Current == this)
        d(state);
    else
    {
        using ManualResetEventSlim mre = new();
        ExceptionDispatchInfo edi = null;
        Post(s =>
        {
            try
            {
                d(s);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                edi = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
            }
            mre.Set();
        }, state);
        mre.Wait();
        edi?.Throw();
    }
}

private void RunContext()
{
    SetSynchronizationContext(this);
    foreach ((SendOrPostCallback d, object state) in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        try
        {
            d(state);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Повторюсь, такая доработка нужна только если закидывать в `Send` и `Post` свои делегаты извне контекста, которые могут выбрасывать исключения. Если использовать только `SendAsync`, то данная доработка не требуется.

Comment: lock вообще можно использовать в асинхронных методах. Нельзя оборачивать await в lock, но сам lock в синхронных кусках кода - пожалуйста. Впрочем, и такая реализация SingleThreadedSynchronizationContext может иногда пригодиться, тем более, что она проще в использовании будет, чем lock. Но раз уж взялся писать вопрос/ответ, имеет наверное смысл тогда и примеры с обработкой исключений привести для будущих читателей.

Comment: @John всё верно. Здесь главный фокус, зачем я это написал, в том, что у меня где-то есть пошаренная между потоками коллекция, точнее нескольно, и я интенсивно с ними работаю. При этом Producer/Consumer выглядел страшновато, еще нужна была работа с индексаторами и гарантия, что пока кусок синхронного кода выполняется, индексы элементов не поедут. Локи спасали, но их было очень много. Снапшоты тоже надоели, и я решил пойти другим путем, и выкинул просто тонны кода, отвечающего за синхронизацию. Теперь всё чисто и понятно.