# Асинхронное программирование и задачи в C#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

У меня есть несколько теоретических вопросов по использованию задач, которые я бы хотел разъяснить для себя.

**В чём смысл использования асинхронных методов?** Правильный асинхронный метод использует внутри себя один или несколько операторов await, которые позволяют дождаться завершения операции не блокируя текущий поток. Как только такой оператор встречается, соответствующая операция запускается асинхронно, а поток, в котором выполнялся метод возвращается в пул потоков. После этого он может приступить к выполнению другой задачи, которая находится в локальной очереди этого потока, а продолжение исходного метода может быть выполнено вообще в любом другом свободном потоке. В чём смысл выполнять асинхронную операцию в другом потоке? Операция в любом случае должна быть выполнена, почему бы исходному потоку не сделать этого? В случае `await Task.Delay` преимущество на лицо: чтобы поток не простаивал без дела, он может заняться выполнением другой задачи, а потом, например, вернуться к выполнению исходного метода. К какого типа операциям в итоге приводят все await (внутри каждого асинхронного метода есть оператор await, который асинхронно ожидает другой асинхронный метод, который так же содержит оператор(ы) await и так далее), что поток блокируется?

**Почему не возможно задать асинхронному методу параметры создания задачи?** Может быть мне важно, чтобы задача, созданная в результате вызова асинхронного метода, выполнялась сразу в отдельном потоке, а не ожидала пока какой-нибудь поток из пула освободится?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567

Comment: Основное правило этого сайта (за счёт чего он и взлетел): одна тема - один вопрос. Про ConfigureAwait и блокировки задайте отдельные вопросы.

Comment: _Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме._

Comment: Смешались в кучу люди, кони. [Многопоточное vs асинхронное программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416086/179763)

Comment: @aepot Это не отвечает на 2 и 4 вопросы. На первый вопрос можно ответить следующим образом: делать метод асинхронным имеет смысл лишь в том случае, когда он зависит от кода, выполнение которого не зависит от нас. Следовательно и на третий вопрос можно ответить утвердительно, ведь метод `Process` в таком случае зависит от выполнения кода на стороне клиента.

Comment: @tym32167 aepot дал ссылку на подобный ответ. На вопросы 2 и 4 это так же не отвечает.

Comment: Касаемо второго вопроса - могу дать конкретный пример. Все вызовы асинхронного метода `Process`, обрабатывающего соединения, будут выполняться в одном потоке (при условии что до начала цикла приёма входящих соединений существовал 1 поток), ведь задача запускается с параметрами по-умолчанию, то есть созданные задачи не будут порождать новые потоки. Это верно?

Comment: Вам написали же, что лучше задавать вопросы отдельно. Мало смысла отвечать на 4 вопроса, а баллов получать как за один.

Comment: Я могу оформить отдельный вопрос про `ConfigureAwait`. Уже оформил отдельный вопрос про блокировки, но оставшиеся 3 вопроса относятся к одной проблеме, разве нет?

Comment: _"Мало смысла отвечать на 4 вопроса, а баллов получать как за один."_ - Интересный подход

Comment: Ваши вопросы разные, так как: 1) Вы упускаете само понятие асинхронного метода. Асинхронный метод - это по сути синтаксический сахар. 2) Наличие await в асинхронном методе не обязано вообще быть связано с каким либо потоком 3) Как следствие, второй вопрос не имеет смысла, так как созданная задача вообще не обязана выполняться в каком либо потоке 4) Третий вопрос вообще не про асинхронщину, а про верную имплементацию серверной стороны используя асинхронщину, что по сути сомостоятельный вопрос сам по себе.

Comment: ну а про набор баллов, практика показала, что люди только на таком примере понимают. Если бы я рассказывал про базу вопросов / ответов или идею сайта, то большиство это пропускает мимо ушей

Comment: @tym32167 Разве поиск по сайту выдал бы разные результаты будь эти вопросы оформлены в одной теме или в разных? По своей тематике они всё же схожи.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450195/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450198/configureawait-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: причем здесь поиск по сайту? Вот вы бы стали хранить инфу обо всех поставщиках макарон в одной строке БД? Наверное нет. Так и здесь, 1 вопрос на сайте - минимальная неделимая чать информации. Если задаете 2 вопроса - задаёте двумя вопросами на сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В чём смысл использования асинхронных методов?

В чем смысл всего асинхронного программирования? В умении [ожидать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567) завершения задач не переставая делать что-то еще.

> Почему не возможно задать асинхронному методу параметры создания задачи?

Возможно. За это отвечает контекст синхронизации, можете его полностью [написать сами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1385260/373567).

По поводу потоков из пула, их там много, и если повесить все сотни тысяч потоков забив весь пул - недостаточно, то что-то у вас в коде пошло явно не так. Опять же асинхронная операция может не занимать потоков на время выполнения [вообще ни одного](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), в большинстве классических случаев ожидания ответа от диска или из сети так и происходит.

Comment: _"Возможно. За это отвечает контекст синхронизации, можете его полностью написать сами."_ - Кроме как создать свой контекст синхронизации существуют решения?

Comment: _"По поводу потоков из пула, их там много"_ - Если существуют один поток и он запускает множество раз один и тот же асинхронный метод в цикле, до первого await'а все задачи будут выполняться синхронно (если мы не переопределим контекст синхронизации)?

Comment: @rock8 1) для async/await - нет 2) неважно сколько задач запускается, сам процесс запуска вообще может быть синхронным, например просто добавление этих задач в коллекцию, а потом ожидание всех сразу в комбинаторе типа `Task.WhenAll`, а вот продолжение кода после await зависит от текущего контекста, и если его нет, оно будет выполнена на потоке из пула. Синхронных пулов не бывает, однопоточные бывают, я показывал. Прекратите путать асинхронность и многопоточность. Это 2 совершенно несвязанные между собой вещи. Об этом тоже было многократно написано в ответах по ссылкам, перечитайте внимательно.

Comment: Проблема в том, что до начала асинхронной операции в рассматриваемом методе может выполняться большое количество вычислений, которые не плохо было бы распараллелить. То есть такой асинхронный метод должен начать выполнение в отдельном потоке, а когда начнется сама асинхронная операция - уже не важно что и где, планировщик сам решит как будет лучше. При этом выполняются и другие асинхронные методы.

Comment: @rock8 Читать https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async, обратить внимание на разницу в подходе к CPU-bound задачам и IO-bound, если непонятно, о чем я, переключите язык статьи на английский, перевод там так себе.