# Использование асинхронности в многопоточном серверном приложении

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Cоздаётся многопоточное серверное приложение. Существует цикл в основном потоке, который принимает входящие соединения. Далее каждое соединение должно обрабатывается в отдельном потоке методом `Process`, который содержит множество вызовов асинхронных методов, читающих или записывающих данные в `Stream`, представляющий соединение. Имеет ли смысл делать метод `Process` асинхронным и запускать обработку каждого соединения отдельной задачей? Как минимум это удобно в плане написания кода, ведь вместо использования `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` можно писать просто await. Так же могут быть задержки связанные с ожиданием получения данных от клиента, которые не будут блокировать поток и он может обрабатывать другие соединения.

Однако, все вызовы асинхронного метода `Process`, обрабатывающего соединения, будут выполняться в одном потоке (при условии что до начала цикла приёма входящих соединений существовал 1 поток), ведь задача запускается с параметрами по-умолчанию, то есть созданные задачи не будут порождать новые потоки. Верно ли это и как исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Имеет смысл ВСЁ делать асинхронным. Если у вас все асинхронно, то у вас везде await, а значит (без дополнительных усилий в виде SyncronizationContext) все это будет перемалываться в пуле потоков.

Comment: Абстрактный вопрос про абстрактный код в абстрактных условиях выполнения. Ну например [вот решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567). Не походит? А что подходит, вы не написали. Вопрос предлагаю удалить, либо конкретизировать.

Comment: _"Абстрактный вопрос"_ - Так и есть. Я не создаю серверное приложение, это теоретический вопрос про использование асинхронных методов. Вопрос в другом: следует ли делать `Process` асинхронным и будут ли все задачи выполняться в одном потоке?

Comment: _это теоретический вопрос_ - сделайте его практическим, начните писать код. А класс `System.Diagnostics.Process` вообще непонятно при чем тут. Отдельный процесс не может работать в одном потоке с текущим. Операционная система запускает каждый новый процесс в одтельном потоке, и это не изменить не переписав саму операционную систему.

Comment: `Process` - название метода, обрабатывающего соединения - это есть в вопросе.

Comment: _"сделайте его практическим, начните писать код"_ - Зачем же? Какой информации о методе `Process` вам не хватает, чтобы дать ответ?

Comment: `Process` это класс в .NET, я советую переименовать метод, потому что это сбивает с толку. Чтобы дать ответ, надо понять вопрос, я не понимаю. Какой-то поток сознания. Всё смешалось, потоки, асинхронность, каша какая-то. А я вам трижды уже писал, чтобы перестали путать асинхронность и многопоточку. Хотите конкретный ответ, задайте конкретный вопрос.

Comment: _"Какой-то поток сознания. Всё смешалось, потоки, асинхронность, каша какая-то."_ - В вопросе чётко сказано: _"Далее каждое соединение должно обрабатывается в отдельном потоке методом Process"_.

Comment: _"А я вам трижды уже писал, чтобы перестали путать асинхронность и многопоточку."_ - Как вы по 2 моим последним комментариям поняли, что я путаю асинхронности и многопоточность? Я лишь указал, что `Process` - название метода и спросил какую информацию об этом методе вы хотели бы услышать. А разницу между 2 этими понятиями я понял в ходе нашего обсуждения ранее.

Comment: _"я советую переименовать метод, потому что это сбивает с толку"_ - Речь не о реальном проекте, вопрос чисто теоретический. Название дано для наглядности ситуации. В плане именования в реальном коде, возможно вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

> Однако, все вызовы асинхронного метода Process, обрабатывающего соединения, будут выполняться в одном потоке (при условии что до начала цикла приёма входящих соединений существовал 1 поток), ведь задача запускается с параметрами по-умолчанию, то есть созданные задачи не будут порождать новые потоки. Верно ли это и как исправить ситуацию?

Глупость полная. Вот типичный цикл приёма соединений:

```cs
while(…) {
    var connection = await listener.Accept();
    var task = Task.Run(() => Process(connection, token));

    someTasksContainer.Add(task);
}

await someTasksContainer.WaitForAllTasks();
```

Задачи, создаваемые через `Task.Run`, могут выполняться в любом потоке пула.