# ConfigureAwait и контекст синхронизации

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Теоретический вопрос. Правильно ли я понимаю, что использование данного метода имеет смысл лишь в UI-приложениях, где есть контекст синхронизации? Вызов `ConfigureAwait(false)` указывает, что не следует запоминать текущий контекст синхронизации и задача может быть выполнена в другом потоке. В противном случае запущенная задача будет 100% выполнена в текущем контексте синхронизации (если он есть) тогда, когда у потока будет на это время.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/681382/22836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `лишь в UI-приложениях, где есть контекст синхронизации` - контекст синхронизации может быть не только в UI приложениях. Например, он был в одной из версий asp.net (потом его выпилили). При этом нет никаких проблем, чтобы создать свой контекст синхронизации для любого потока любого вида приложения.
2. `ConfigureAwait(false) указывает, что не следует запоминать текущий контекст синхронизации и задача может быть выполнена в другом потоке` - `ConfigureAwait` не указывает где будет выполнена задача, а указывает где будет выполнен код, следующий за задачей (то есть где будет выполнено продолжение задачи)

```
// Какой то код 1
await myTask.ConfigureAwait(...);
// Какой то код 2
```

Из примера выше, `ConfigureAwait` указывает, где будет выполнен `Какой то код 2`

3. `и задача может быть выполнена в другом потоке` - `ConfigureAwait` никак не определяет, где будет выполнена сама задача. Сама задача может быть выполнена как угодно при этом и для её выполнения не всегда нужен вообще какой либо поток.

Как резюме:
Использовать `ConfigureAwait(false)` следует во всех случаях, когда вам не важно, в каком потоке будет выполнен `Какой то код 2`. Как исключение, вы можете опустить `ConfigureAwait(false)` если точно знаете, что код не будет выполняться никогда в потоке с контекстом синхронизации. То есть если весь код, где у вас нет `ConfigureAwait(false)` вызывается только вами и больше никем.