# Блокирующее ожидание Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, асинхронность

Уже спросил на англоязычном форуме, ответы меня не устраивают.

На самом деле я изучаю `async/wait` и пытаюсь увидеть для себя преимущество `await Task.WhenAll` по сравнению с `Task.WaitAll` в операциях, связанных с процессором. Поскольку все пишут, что `Task.WaitAll` обеспечивает блокирующее ожидание, а `await Task.WhenAll` обеспечивает неблокирующее ожидание.

Я создал пример, в котором хотел заменить `Task.WaitAll` на `await Task.WhenAll` и своими глазами увидеть, что появился еще один свободный поток. Но я вижу, что даже `Task.WaitAll` не блокирует поток. И мой вопрос связан с этим. В случае с `Task.WaitAll` я вижу, что в том же потоке, в котором выполняется `Task.WaitAll`, выполняется другая задача. Но если я включу `Thread.Sleep` или `while (true)` вместо `Task.WaitAll`, то поведение программы станет ожидаемым.

Я думал, что метод `Main` создаст задачу MyTask (-1 рабочий поток), которая создаст 16 задач условно B1-B16 (-15 рабочих потоков, так как 1 рабочий поток занят задачей MyTask, а всего рабочих потоков 16), задача MyTask будет иметь блокирующее ожидание `Task.WaitAll`, и я увижу 15 из 16 запущенных задач. Но я вижу все 16 запущенных задач, и одна из них выполняется в том же потоке, что и задача MyTask.

**Вопрос**.
Почему в этом примере`Task.WaitAll` не блокирует поток, в котором он выполняется, в отличие от `Thread.Sleep` или `while (true)`? Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить пошагово, как работает код двух задач в потоке 4 в случае использования `Task.WaitAll`? Почему поток, в котором выполняется задача MyTask, также используется условно задачей B16?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Main                Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

            int ProcessorCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(ProcessorCount, ProcessorCount);
            int Counter = 0;
            List<Task> MyListForTask = new List<Task>();

            void MyMethod()
            {
                lock (MyListForTask)
                {
                    Counter++;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Counter: {Counter}        Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                }
                
                //Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue);
                while (true) { };
            }

            Task MyTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"MyTask            Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < ProcessorCount; i++)
                {
                    MyListForTask.Add(Task.Run(MyMethod));
                }

                //Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue);
                //while (true) { };
                Task.WaitAll(MyListForTask.ToArray());                
            });

            MyTask.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: А дайте ссылку на англоязычный вопрос. Интересно, что там написали )

Comment: @CrazyElf, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74546215/blocking-waiting-of-task-waitall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличное наблюдение. `Task.WaitAll` действительно каким-то образом позволяет [шедьюлеру](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) взять его поток и использовать в дочерних задачах. Ну а почему нет, если он не может завершиться, пока все что внутри не завершится. Браво, майкрософт, отличная работа с потоками, ни потока мимо.

С другой стороны, этот поток, который заблочен такой синхронной ожидалкой как `WaitAll`, вы все равно никак не сможете использовать. Например, запустите `WaitAll` из UI потока Windows Forms. Если бы ваше подозрение было верным, форма бы не зависла. А всё потому, что диспетчер UI потока и шедьюлер не могут и не должны договориться.

Хотя в тех же винформах отрабатывает другой фокус - сделайте блокирующий вызов второй формы через `ShowDialog`, но при этом родительская форма продолжит быть жизнеспособной, в ней можно менять например текст в лейбле, отрисовка изменений пройдет без проблем. В дотнете на самом деле много таких приколов в оптимизациях, ясно только одно: вы не сможете использовать заблокированный поток далее в своих целях.

С другой стороны, когда пишешь асинхронный код, о потоках вообще не думаешь, потому что работа с потоками - проблемы контекста синхронизации. Есть разница - синхронный вызов и асинхронный вызов. Асинхронный возвращает в вызывающий поток `Task` сразу как только внутри себя сам начал асинхронную работу, например наткнулся на `await`.

Вот в чем главная разница:

```
Task task = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
Console.WriteLine("привет, я свободный поток");
task.Wait();
```

То есть даже при отсутствии контекста синхронизации и без использования `async/await` выгода от использования асинхронных операций очевидна.

Второй аспект, который я расписывать не буду, это возможность отмены. Подавляющее большинство асинхронных методов а .NET принимают `CancellatoionToken` в качестве аргумента. Вы не можете отменить тот же `Thread.Sleep` пока он не выспится полностью, а `Task.Delay` сможете в любой момент.

Фокусируйте внимание не на номерах потоков, а на поведении кода при асинхронном программировании. Потоки уходят на фон и выполняют служебную функцию. Потоки - это тема многопоточного программирования, а не асинхронного. Данные темы не стоит путать. Многопоточное программирование про одновременное выполнение, асинхронное - про одновременное ожидание.

> Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить пошагово, как работает код двух задач в потоке 4 в случае использования `Task.WaitAll`?

Магия оптимизаций .NET! :) В этом нет никакого секрета, истина где-то в открытых исходниках самого дотнета. Я покопался, раскопки привели меня в недра `ManualResetEventSlim`, и там я потерялся в низкоуровневой работе с ресурсами операционной системы Windows, хотя с очень большой вероятностью она тут не при чем и я просто заблудился.

> На самом деле я изучаю `async/await` и пытаюсь увидеть для себя преимущество `await Task.WhenAll` по сравнению с `Task.WaitAll`

Оно очевидно в фрагменте кода выше. А все эти номера потоков это не для вас преимущество, а для операционной системы и пула потоков. Последний вообще к асинхронному программированию не имеет никакого отношения. Можно смастерить вообще [однопоточный контекст синхронизации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1385260/373567), и это никак не помешает писать полноценный асинхронный код.

Comment: Спасибо, значит как и ожидалось - подкапотная муть .NET. Не впервые. Нужно было подтверждение более умных людей.

Comment: В некоторых местах документации MIcrosoft прямо говорится, что некоторые задачи могут запускаться на основном потоке. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism#use-caution-when-waiting-in-delegates-that-are-called-by-parallelinvoke) (и последний раздел)

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться в деталях, наверняка aepot напишет лучше ответ. И тем не менее.

1. Насчёт переиспользования потока - вопрос тонкий, я не готов ответить. Но в общем случае асинхронному `Task`-у вообще не обязателен отдельный поток. Вам нужно подразобраться в чём разница между многопоточностью и асинхронностью. Асинхронное выполнение нескольких задач возможно и в одном потоке, просто периодически переключается контекст. Для начала вам лучше по отдельности эти концепции поизучать и покрутить по-всякому. Здесь вы их смешиваете, вас это только запутает. У вас тут нет ни одного `await`, но есть много `Task`-ов, это только запутывает ситуацию.
2. Разницу между `Task.WaitAll` и `Task.WhenAll` вы не видите потому, что у вас нет `await`-ов снаружи `MyTask`. Вот если бы `MyTask` был полноценным асинхронным методом, ожидавшимся через `await` (или через другой `Task.WhenAll`) где-то снаружи, то поток должен был бы освободиться, а на `Task.WaitAll` он должен был бы висеть. Но из-за `MyTask.Wait();` что внутри не напиши, а эта инструкция всё-равно должна по идее заблокировать текущий поток.

Я вижу как-то так, хотя наверняка могу ошибаться.

P.S. Про `ThreadPool` убрал, был не прав.

Comment: `Task.Run` по умолчанию делает `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 1) Вижу своими глазами что влияет. Докажите. Запустите задач, которые будут работать до упора, больше, чем указанный лимит в `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`. 2) и 3) Вопрос не про теорию. Вопрос максимально конкретный про практику. Есть пример. Как это работает? Почему в `MyTask` - `while(true)` или `Thread.Sleep` не дают запуститься условно 16-ой задаче, а якобы блокирующее ожидание `Task.WaitAll` дает, при этом в том же потоке. Это именно то, что меня интересует.

Comment: @aepot Понятно, тут у меня значит пробел. Был )

Comment: @NikVladi А эффект устойчивый, вы много раз запускали и всё время картина была одинаковая?

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, одинаковая. Я видел разные глюки в .NET и на git писал куда надо. Допускаю как то, что я не понимаю что-то, так и то, что это глюк. Разобраться хочется.

Comment: @NikVladi Функции `while(true)` и `Thread.Sleep` это обычные синхронные функции и они разумеется тормозят текущих поток. А `WaitAll()` это асинхронная функция. А суть асинронности вообще то как раз в том, что бы такая задача не занимала поток. И она его не занимает. Любая потенциально асинхронная функция в тот момент когда ей надо реально чего то ждать подает сигнал планировщику [асинхронных] задач, тот переключает стек на другую область и выполняет с этим стеком другую асинхронную задачу в том же потоке, до тех пор пока та не завершиться или не решит сама чего то подождать.

Comment: @Mike Да вот теоретически вроде бы всё понятно, у товарища вопрос, почему практика с теорией не бьётся )

Comment: @Mike, запустите код и скажите занимает ли `WaitAll` поток? Занимает. `int ProcessorCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(ProcessorCount, ProcessorCount);

Task t = Task.Delay(int.MaxValue);

for (int i = 0; i < ProcessorCount * 2; i++)
{
    Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine(Task.CurrentId); Task.WaitAll(t); });
}

Task.WaitAll(t);`

Comment: @NikVladi Если задача назначена на поток, это не значит что она в этом потоке занимает процессор. Вы сами показали, что у вас 2 задачи находятся одновременно в потоке 4. И это правильно, просто одна из них (ну фактически конечно обе, просто третьей задачи на тот же поток не нашлось) в состоянии ожидания, ее стек отложен в сторону и поток команд передан другой задаче

Comment: @NikVladi - _Запустите задач, которые будут работать до упора, больше, чем указанный лимит в ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads_ - легко, если внутри этих задач будет `await` внутри цикла.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну как бы спорно, ведь если контекст null, то континуация встыкается в тот же пул потоков. А если не null, то он сам решает. (см. реализацию `SynchronizationContext`)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, выше @Mike писал о `WaitAll`, я на это и реагировал и привел конкретный пример. await к `Task.WaitAll` не применить, к `Task.Run` можно, но станет только хуже, дальше первой задачи дело не пойдет. Если `Task.WaitAll` заменить на `await Task.WhenAll`, то да, все ок. Но речь шла о - я цитирую @Mike - "А WaitAll() это асинхронная функция. А суть асинронности вообще то как раз в том, что бы такая задача не занимала поток. И она его не занимает.". Но `WaitAll` как раз занимает. Но иногда, как мы убедились, занимает "с перерывами".