# Как связанны TaskScheduler и SynchronizationContext в C#?

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть некоторое непонимание относительно связи этих механизмов.
Как я понимаю TaskScheduler - это механизм для планировки выполнения задач, по умолчанию используется планировщик пула потоков. Но так-же есть планировщик текущего контекста синхронизации. Контекст синхронизации - это механизм который выполняет наш код в определенном месте, как я понимаю он есть только в приложениях в пользовательским интерфейсом(по умолчанию). Напрашивается вопрос - у контекста синхронизации есть свой собственный планировщик? Я могу получить к нему доступ? Как эти два понятия работают между собой?

P.S - видел похожий вопрос на англоязычной версии сайта - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580061/what-is-the-conceptual-difference-between-synchronizationcontext-and-taskschedul. Но из него я так и не смог получить ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Контекст синхронизации это и есть планировщик сам по себе. Только его задача - работа с async/await, с асинхронным контекстом ExecutionContext. А на базе TaskScheduler работают методы TPL типа Parallel или ContinueWith. Чтобы получить доступ к текущему контексту синхронизации, обратитесь к SynchronizationContext.Current, и вызовите ему Send или Post. Вот и вся магия. Пример реализации собственного контекста: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1385260/373567, почитать по теме можно здесь: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/

Comment: TaskSheduler планирует выполнение задач в потоках, а SynchronizationContext отвечает за планирование выполнения работы в задаче

Comment: @Nikolay есть задача Task (ожидание, асинхронность) и поток Thread (выполнение, многопоточность), а у вас откуда-то три сущности появилось.

Comment: @aepot кто то же должен управлять выполнением statemachine асинхронного метода. Например то в каком потоке будет продолжено выполнение кода метода после await