# Работа с Task (async/await) из главного потока в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, async-await, task, coroutine

Есть код, который записывает текст в какое-либо поле данных UnityCloud:

```
public async void WriteTimer(string status)
{
    var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "name", ActiveModule.gameObject.name },
        { "status", status }
    };

    var response = await CloudCodeService.Instance.CallEndpointAsync("SetTime", arguments);
}
```

И есть кнопка, которая должна ожидать завершения async метода, чтоб изменить своё состояние.

Как заставить кнопку ожидать ответа от Task?

**P.S.** Моя конструкция Task, такого формата:

```
public async Task WriteTimer(string status)
{
    var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "name", ActiveModule.gameObject.name },
        { "status", status }
    };

    await Task.Run(()=>CloudCodeService.Instance.CallEndpointAsync("SetTime", arguments));
}
```

А так же дальнейшее ожидание `await WriteTimer(status);` в кнопке не дало результата.

(*UnityException: get_gameObject can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.*)

Поэтому в данный момент вся конструкция работает на корутинах синхронно ожидая ответа от асинхронного метода (*Знаю, что так нельзя*).

Comment: _синхронно ожидая ответа от асинхронного метода_ - показали бы как именно, подсказал бы как вылечить.

Comment: @aepot использую IEnumerator, жду n-ое количество времени в нем, далее код продолжает работу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу скажу, красивого решения пока нет. Разработчики Unity сейчас работают над тем чтобы реализовать `async/await` как надо, ждемс. Поэтому если не изобретать, то корутины вполне себе нормальное решение.

Смысл проблемы в том, что в Unity пока нет рабочего контекста синхронизации, то есть продолжение асинхронного метода будет выполнено на потоке из пула, так себя ведет `SynchronizationContext` по умолчанию. Но при этом сам движок на уровне скриптов однопоточный. Поэтому нужна какая-то синхронизация.

Альтернативно вы можете запустить асинхронную операцию.

```
Task task = CloudCodeService.Instance.CallEndpointAsync("SetTime", arguments);
```

Куда-то этот таск положить, в поле например.

А затем например каждый кадр его проверять

```
if (task.IsCompleted)
{
    try
    {
        // таск завершен
        task.Wait(); // для Task
        //var result = task.Result; // для Task<T>

        // здесь можно что-то сделать с результатом или отреагировать на то что таск завершился.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

И всё, никаких корутин, только поллинг. Unity-стайл. :)

---

С другой стороны, `async/await` не магия же какая-то. Можно и приручить, правда уже получится кода побольше. Из нехороших штук, придется использовать тот же поллинг, то есть `Update` для разгребания очереди асинхронных коллбэков.

Давайте ради интереса и обучения создадим такой контекст синхронизации.

```
public class SingleThreadedSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<(SendOrPostCallback, object)> _queue = new();

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue((d, state));
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        if (Current == this)
            d(state);
        else
        {
            using ManualResetEventSlim mre = new();
            ExceptionDispatchInfo edi = null;
            Post(s =>
            {
                try
                {
                    d(s);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    edi = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex); // ловим исключение в колбэке
                }
                mre.Set();
            }, state);
            mre.Wait();
            edi?.Throw(); // выбрасываем пойманное исключение в вызывающей точке
        }
    }

    public void Init(bool force = false)
    {
        if (Current is null || force)
            SetSynchronizationContext(this);
        else if (Current != this)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Уже существует другой контекст синхронизации {Current.GetType().Name}, не удается проинициализировать контекст");
    }

    public bool ExecuteCallback()
    {
        if (_queue.TryDequeue(out var t))
        {
            (SendOrPostCallback d, object state) = t;
            d(state);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Много всего непонятно, ну да ладно. Теперь как это вкрутить в Unity. Пусть будет вот такой скрипт.

```
public class SynchronizationBehavior : MonoBehavior
{
     private SingleThreadedSynchronizationContext _context;
     
     void Awake()
     {
         _context = new SingleThreadedSynchronizationContext();
         _context.Init();
     }

     void Update()
     {
          while (_context.ExecuteCallback()) { } // разгрести очередь колбэков
     }
}
```

Теперь этот скрипт в одном экземпляре нужно куда-то навесить.

Теперь вы сможете в любом другом скрипте выполнить асинхронный код не вывалившись из контекста синхронизации.

```
void Start()
{
    WriteTimer("...");
}

public async void WriteTimer(string status)
{
    try
    {
        var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "name", ActiveModule.gameObject.name },
            { "status", status }
        };

        var response = await CloudCodeService.Instance.CallEndpointAsync("SetTime", arguments);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

В `async void` методах обязательно оборачивайте весь код в `try-catch`.

`await Task.Run(()=> ...)` для асинхронных методов делать не нужно. Это бессмысленно.

*Больше про однопоточный контекст синхронизации я писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1385260/373567) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1266820/373567).*

Comment: Благодарю, необходима была именно эта информация

Comment: @Somebody просто интеренсно, что именно из этого пригодилось? Может убрать что-то лишнее.

Comment: Решил использовать поллинг, однако с некоторыми улучшениями, дабы не ломиться каждый кадр в проверку выполнения Task, мне в первую очередь необходим не столько немедленный результат от выполнения Task, сколько алгоритм, который гарантированно получит ответ, но я бы оставил полный текст вашего ответа, т.к не ровен час, что где то придется и приручать асинхронность.